# NGINX secure_link returning 403

Tags: nginx, web-server, md5

I´m using the following serve block to serve some mp4 files using NGINX secure link.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/cdn;
        index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name cdn.server.xyz;

        location /v {
            root /var/www/cdn/videos;
            secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
            secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr supersecret";

            if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
            if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
        }

}
```

And the following PHP code to generate the hash:

```
<?php
$expires = time()+7200;  # e.g. 2 hours url expiry would be time()+7200;
$domain = 'http://cdn.server.xyz';
$uri = urldecode('/v/test.mp4'); #uri
$ip = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'; 
$secure_text = 'supersecret';

function getSecureHash($ip, $uri, $secure_text, $expires){
 $str = $expires.$uri.$ip.' '.$secure_text;
 $tmp = md5( $str, true );
 $tmp1 = base64_encode( $tmp );
 return str_replace( array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', ''), $tmp1 );
}
$url = "$domain$uri?md5=".getSecureHash($ip, $uri, $secure_text, $expires)."&expires=$expires";
echo $url;
```

The problem that I'm stucked is that for any request, I'm having the 403 error.

Here is the nginx error.log (https://pastebin.com/UkfQWttC)
Any suggestion that what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in nginx `error.log`?

Comment: This is the only error at the error.log: [error] 151078#151078: *9 open() "/var/www/cdn/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: Then I suggest you enable debug logging in nginx (the way depends on nginx distribution) and then see if there is further information about the reason for 403 error.

Comment: I´ve pasted the error.log at debug level here. (https://pastebin.com/UkfQWttC). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[nginx secure link documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) states that the MD5 hash value should be encoded with [base64url](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5).

However, in your code you are using normal Base64 encode, which is different. You can use functions described in [Base64.guru](https://base64.guru/developers/php/examples/base64url) to perform base64url encoding in PHP.

The difference between base64 and base64 encoding is that `+` is replaced with `-` and `/` is replaced with `_`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, after changing to generate using base64url I still having the 403 error.